# ionic native ios plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm following the official [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html) 
to implement a native iOS plugin for ionic. What I'm a bit confused about is where the native code should be placed. Should it be under plugins or platforms/ios. Any tutorial explaning how to implement native plugins for iOS on cordova would be helpful.

Thanks

Update:

- I've added the Echo.h and Echo.m to plugins/echo/src/ios
- echo.js to plugis/echo/www
- Updated the config.xml file

When I try to call

```
window.echo("echome", function(echoValue) {
        alert(echoValue == "echome"); // should alert true.
});
```

Its saying TypeError: window.echo is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you install a cordova plugin it normally goes to the plugin folder in your application project:
`myApp/plugings`
If you then do `cordova build` or `ionic build` the plugin will be 'installed' to the platforms. 
So basically cordove takes care for you about the installation process.